# Plots points on image in angular 6

Tags: angular

I am using an angular 6 project in that I want to achieve below scenario

In the below image that I provided, whenever the user clicks on any portion of the body (On the white color) the X, Y coordinate of that point should be pushed into the array and small circle will be a plot on that X, Y co-ordinate.

If the user clicks anywhere apart from the white color, then that co-ordinates would not be considered to push into an array.

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd6ezf?embed=1

[image]
please give me the possible solution for this. Thanks in advance.

I have tried 
**Html**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480" (click)="getPosition($event)"
    style="cursor:crosshair;background:url(https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/silhouettes-of-man-and-woman_23-2147505840.jpg)"></canvas>
```

**TS**

```
getPosition(event) {
this.element = <Element>this.root;
this.canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById("canvas");
this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
let curleft = 0,
  curtop = 0;

curleft += event.offsetX;
curtop += event.offsetY;
 this.drawCoordinates(curleft, curtop);
}


 drawCoordinates(x, y) {

const grd = this.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 170, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "black");
grd.addColorStop(1, "red");
this.ctx.fillStyle = grd; // Red color

this.ctx.beginPath();
this.ctx.arc(Number(x), Number(y), this.pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
this.ctx.fill();

 const coord = "x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
 const p = this.ctx.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
 const hex = "#" + ("000000" + rgbToHex(p[0], p[1], p[2])).slice(-6);
 jQuery('#status').html(coord + "<br>" + hex);
}
```

In the status tag, I got the same color every time

Comment: Feel free to post your tried code!

Comment: @prashantPimpale thanks for replying I have added code

Comment: How I can try this code? StackBlitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rd6ezf?embed=1 I have created project on stackblitz

Comment: Have a look at:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sspqve which is currently not complete but due to time have started to get x and y in the above ex. You can try

Comment: Thanks but not getting the proper result that I want :(